# Destructuring assignment and variable swapping

Tags: javascript, node.js, variable-assignment, destructuring

Javascript allows swapping of variables:

```
var x = 1
var y = 2

[x, y] = [y, x] // y = 1 , x = 2
```

And destructured assignment:

```
var a, b
[a, b] = [1, 2]

log(a) // 1
log(b) // 2
```

When using variable swapping in lieu with destructured assignment, trying to swap variables breaks down:

```
var a, b
[a, b] = [1, 2] // a = 1, b = 2

[a, b] = [b, a] // TypeError: Cannot set property '2' of undefined
```

Why is that?

Comment: It works in chrome(56.0.2924.87), what browser you are running? , are you using a transpiler or node ?

Comment: I don't get that error, but one thing I'd do is add a semicolon after the first assignment (`[a, b] = [1, 2];`).

Comment: I'm using Node 7.4.0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you decide to omit semicolons (no judgement, I prefer it that way too), don't forget to prefix lines beginning with array literals with `;`. Occasionally, semicolon insertion *does* matter, because it might not occur when you want or expect it to.

```js
var a, b
;[a, b] = [1, 2]

;[a, b] = [b, a]

console.log(a, b)
```

Comment: Thank you @gyre. Would you mind explaining why exactly the semicolons are needed in this case? Or give a pointer to a resource explaining it?

Comment: Basically, the JS engine sees this when you don't use semicolons: `var a, b; [a, b] = [1, 2][a, b] = [b, a]`. Some of the array literals are interpreted as property accesses, and the commas used to separate elements are interpreted as [the comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/ka/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) instead.

Comment: For more information, I would suggest reading [this section on ASI in Kyle Simpson's book *You Don't Know JS*](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20&%20grammar/ch5.md#automatic-semicolons).